# Is there a way to create a fake dataset which can satisfy expected effects?

Tags: r, dataset, logistic-regression

I need to create a fake data set. I know the variables, the range of values they could take and also have a rough idea on the size of their effects (thus also the direction of the effect). Do you have any idea if there is a way to do this?

Thank you!

I've created a shiny flex dashboard which should show how likely is one person to buy a product depending on his/her characteristics and how with more data, the precision of the predictions increase.
I have to present the dashboard in order to get access to the real data. However, I know the variables and the direction of their effects on the dependent variable.
DFgen oder charlata are not of any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sample`. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(1)
ids <- sample(10000, 50) # create a sample of length 50 from the numbers up to 10000
var1 <- sample(seq(0, 10, 1), 50, replace = TRUE) # the range of values are between 0 and 10
var2 <- sample(seq(10, 500, 20), 50, replace = TRUE) 
var3 <- sample(c("F", "M"), 50, replace = TRUE)
effect <- sample(c(0,1), 50, replace = TRUE) # if you have an idea on the effect, you can apply some if statements here.
# 
df <- data.frame(id = ids,
                 v1 = var1,
                 v2 = var2,
                 v3 = var3,
                 res = effect)
```

This should get you started. You can change the size if you like, instead of 50 choose whatever suitable.